# XmlDocument readAttribute value only if present

Tags: c#, xmldocument, xmlreader

I have an xml as below

```
<xml>
<action OptAttr ="true">somevalue1</action>
<action>somevalue2</action>
<action OptAttr ="true">somevalue3</action>
</xml>
```

OptAttribute is an optional attribute which may not be present in all nodes.
I want to retrive both OptAttr(if present) and somevalue1,2 etc.

Best way to do using xmldocument/xmlreader?

thanks,
Adarsh

Comment: Please show us the code you are using currently. i.e. What have you tried?

Comment: what have you tried? You can get all these using XmlDocument.

value can be retrieved using XmlNode.InnerXml and attributes using XmlNode.Attributes

Comment: Maybe better using linq to xml? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/bb387098.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Linq to Xml is available to you, then I recommend to use it

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(path_to_xml);
var actions = from a in xdoc.Root.Elements("action")
              select new {
                  Value = (string)a,
                  OptAttr = (bool?)a.Attribute("OptAttr")
              };
```

This query parses actions into following anonymous objects:

```
[
  { Value: "somevalue1",  OptAttr: true },
  { Value: "somevalue2",  OptAttr: null },
  { Value: "somevalue3",  OptAttr: true }
]
```

If you want to use default value(e.g. false) for OptAttr instead of nullable boolean, then you can provide it with [null-coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx)

```
OptAttr = (bool?)a.Attribute("OptAttr") ?? false
```

UPDATE: Parsing actions into list of ObjectA:

```
List<ObjectA> actions = (from a in xdoc.Root.Elements("action")
                         select new ObjectA {
                            Value = (string)a,
                            OptAttr = (bool?)a.Attribute("OptAttr")
                         }).ToList();
```

Or lambda syntax (I don't like to mix it with query syntax)

```
var actions = xdoc.Root.Elements("action")
                  .Select(a => new ObjectA {
                       Value = (string)a,
                       OptAttr = (bool?)a.Attribute("OptAttr")
                   }).ToList();
```

Comment: I like this implementation, instead of var actions, can I put them into a list<ObjectA>? (OBjectA is a class with these two attributes I am trying to fetch.)

Comment: awesome, perfect. Need to use linq wherever possible in my code